# C 2 dimensional array dynamic allocation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, declaration, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
struct Cases
    {
        int number;
        char *name[][20];
    };
```

I have this struct, which the size of the two dimensional array is unknown. I try to allocate size for it but i get a error.

```
int main()
    {
        struct Cases Real;
    
        Real.name = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
        if (Real.name == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
.
.
.
```

Comment: `char *name[][20]` - this is an array of arrays of arrays of chars. It's an array of arrays of strings. It's an array of paragraphs. What should this `name` symbolize? Someone has an array of arrays of names? What are you trying to model?

Comment: `name` is a flexible array member (since its outer size is unspecified), not a pointer, so you can't assign to it.  And it's not a `char *`, so `3 * sizeof(char)` wouldn't give a useful size.

Comment: You seem to mix an [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and general pointers. Please make up your mind what you want.

Comment: @KamilCuk i will get city names from the user and store it in the array, but the size will be chaning constantly so i cant define it from the beginning. I have to allocate it everytime.

Comment: `i will get city names from the user and store it in the array` So maybe do `struct User { char *city; char *name };` and then `struct Cases { int number; struct User *users; }`? What will be changing constantly? The cities which users are in?

Comment: @KamilCuk at first the size of the array is 3, after 3 city names entered it should be increased by one to enter the 4th one

Comment: @user253751: `char *name[][20]` declares an array of arrays of 20 pointers to `char`. To declare a pointer to an array of array of `char`, it would have to be `char (*name)[][20]`.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
char *name[][20];
```

declares an array with unknown size.

That is this structure declaration

```
struct Cases
{
    int number;
    char *name[][20];
};
```

declares a structure with a flexible array member.

However you may not assign arrays with pointers like in this statement

```
Real.name = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

Moreover the call of `malloc` does not make a sense.

But it seems you mean a declaration of a pointer instead of an array. That is the structure should look like

```
struct Cases
{
    int number;
    char ( *name )[20];
};
```

If you want to allocate an array of 3 "rows" then you should write

```
Real.name = malloc(3 * sizeof(char[20]));
```

If you want to declare an array of pointers to string literals then the declaration of the structure can look like

```
struct Cases
{
    int number;
    char **name;
};
```

In this case you can allocate memory the following way

```
Real.name = malloc( 3 * sizeof( char * ) );
```

And then you can assign an element of the allocated array for example like

```
Real.name[0] = "test";
```

Comment: Lets say elements of the name are {'test', 'test', 'test'} , here it has 3 members. Everytime new name is entered the size should be increased by one. So that is why i am using pointers to allocating memory later on.

Comment: ok i got it man thanks a lot, just one more question if try to get the name like this `scanf("%s", &Real.name[0]);` will it work ?

Comment: @Carl It can work for the first declaration of the data member not for the second.

Comment: Yeah i just tried it but program crashes, any ideas how should i get the data ?

Comment: @Carl Here is a demonstrative program that workds fine. #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Cases
{
    int number;
    char ( *name )[20];
};

int main(void) {
 
 struct Cases Real = { 3, NULL };
 
 Real.name = malloc( Real.number * sizeof(char[20]));
 
 scanf( "%19s", Real.name[0] );
 
 puts( Real.name[0] );
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: Or in case the intention was to create a VLA, is should be `struct Cases* c = malloc(sizeof *c + sizeof(char* [n][20]));`